# Ruby NoMethodError (undefined method `map') in Post Request

Tags: ruby, post, http-post

I'm trying to do a POST request from a ruby app and I'm getting the following error.

Here is the code:

```
 def action_reply(token,action_id,reply_text)
  require 'uri'
  require 'net/http'
  require 'net/https'

  @reply = { 'ACTION_ID' => action_id, 'text' => reply_text }.to_json
  #A token is required to do this post
  @token_url = 'https://example.com/reply?oauth_token=' + token
  uri = URI.parse(@token_url)
  response = Net::HTTP.post_form(uri,@reply)
end
```

I'm getting an error in the last step that says:

```
 NoMethodError (undefined method `map' for #<String:0x000000063798e8>)
```

Any idea why this is?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Because you're passing a string to a method expecting a hash: remove the `to_json` call.

*Unrelated, but is it necessary to have those instance variables be instance variables?*

Comment: Thanks, that worked!
(And regarding the instance variables, I was just trying to make the example clear)